# How can we pull data using custom SQL from the External database into Alibaba Quick BI?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I need to pull the data from the external database using SQL into Quick BI without using RDS.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no option there for writing SQL for the external database but do they have for Apsara RDS...